# Group list of dates based on values from joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=261cd5bb71c61ad62fa3f23253b369cf)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    channel VARCHAR,
    sales DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, country, channel, sales)
VALUES 
('2020-01-04', 'DE', 'channel_01', '500'),
('2020-01-04', 'FR', 'channel_01', '900'),
('2020-01-04', 'NL', 'channel_01', '100'),

('2020-02-20', 'DE', 'channel_01', '0'),
('2020-02-20', 'FR', 'channel_01', '0'),
('2020-02-20', 'NL', 'channel_01', '0'),

('2020-03-15', 'DE', 'channel_01', '700'),
('2020-03-15', 'FR', 'channel_01', '500'),
('2020-03-15', 'NL', 'channel_03', '300');


/* Table Dates */
CREATE TABLE dates (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE
);

INSERT INTO dates
(date) 
SELECT generate_series ('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-31'::date, interval '1 day');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
date_list     |    country 
--------------|--------------------------
2020-01-01    |      DE
2020-01-01    |      FR
2020-01-01    |      NL
--------------|---------------------------
2020-01-02    |      DE
2020-01-02    |      FR
2020-01-02    |      NL
--------------|---------------------------
:             |      :
:             |      :
:             |      :
--------------|--------------------------
2020-12-29    |      DE
2020-12-30    |      NL 
2020-12-31    |      FR
```

---

I want to list all dates from table `dates` and group them by all countries that are available in table `sales` no matter if the date exist in both tables. So far I have developed this query:

```
SELECT 
d.date AS date_list,
t2.country
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT
    s.event_date,
    s.country,
    s.sales
    FROM sales s
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ORDER BY 1,2) t2 ON t2.event_date = d.date

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

However, it only groups the results by country if the `s.event_date` matches the `d.date`. 
How do I have to modify the query to get the expected result?

Comment: Why the `group by` if you are not aggregating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand your requirements right, but seems it is about CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT D.DATE,X.COUNTRY
FROM DATES AS D
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY FROM SALES
)X
```